# Xcode freezes when running app after Yosemite update

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to Yosemite, Xcode has been unable to run apps on the device. Every time I click on the "Run" button or I do command-R, Xcode freezes. It installs the app on the device, but never launches it. It shows the busy spinning disc and stops responding. Even force quitting Xcode does not help. I have to restart the laptop in order to get Xcode to start again.

I tried it on several apps. These are apps I have been working on for months, it was working fine before Yosemite update.

Things I tried:

- I tried installing Xcode 6.2 beta as well. The same happens on both old and new beta Xcode
- Restarted the laptop several times.
- Deleted and re-installed both versions of Xcode.
- Tried running in non-fullscreen mode.
- Check to make sure English is the primary language.
- Cleared the DerivedData folder completely
- Ran the following commands:

> ```
>    rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode
>    rm -rf $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.*
>    rm -rf $HOME/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
>    rm -rf $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode
> ```

None of the above seem to work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really helped in the end. It just seemed to be a faulty incremental install on Yosemite, esp. since no one else seemed to face the issue. I couldn't even launch Xcode after sometime.
I just had to back stuff up and make a fresh install after formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the subfolders of Derived Data. Go to `~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData` (open the Finder, press cmd+G) and delete all the subfolders. Then restart Xcode. If that doesn't fix the issue, press cmd+shift+K to clean up your project from useless files.

Comment: Thanks, I had deleted files from DeviredData folder. I followed your commands again though, I didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Xcode freezes"? Perhaps you built a bugged app and Xcode is pausing it. Does this happen with all the apps you create?

Comment: What if you create an app from scratch? Does the same thing happen again? If yes, upload that app made from scratch so we can download it and test it on our Mac.

Comment: Same thing is happening to a new empty project as well. The app is uploaded here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8F29_vzzYJJflQ5TVFOTEtNd25ZV2pMMWpMQ2J0R3VXcFNqRml3ZTJxSUxEZ2tiZVJjeTQ&usp=sharing

Comment: I was myself able to download this project on another machine with Yosemite on it and run successfully on the device. I doubt the project would be of much help there.